# Is “the holiest of all other rivers” correct?

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions, superlatives

> Everyone agrees that the Yamuna is the holiest of all other rivers of the world.

I think it is correct. But some people are saying that it should be **Yamuna is holier than any other river of the world.**

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking only about the comparison, or are you also asking about removing "Everyone agrees" ?

Comment: Neither of those. I suggest "the holiest river in the world". We use the superlative to mean "more than any other" so that we can say something more simply than "holier than any other".

Comment: 'The _other_ rivers' are the ones which are _not_ the Yamuna, so it can't be the holiest of them.

Comment: Even if you amend the sentence to "_Everyone_ agrees that the Yamuna is the holiest of all the rivers of the world", it cannot be correct, because I don't agree. I don't believe in holy rivers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey While I too don't find any rivers holier than any others, is your criticism not about your beliefs rather than about English grammar/idiom.  On that basis, would you not disqualify any sentence concerning beliefs that you did not share. (The last line is James K's answer loses the distinction too.)

Answer (score 4):

The use of "all other" with "holiest" is incorrect.

You should either say  "the holiest of all rivers"  or "holier than all other rivers".

This is because "holier" is a comparative, and so you can use it to compare the Yamuna with "other" rivers.  Or you can form a superlative "holiest" in which case you use "of all X" as you are not making a direct comparison.

<sub>Really, Yamuna the holiest river? Even in Hinduism, surely the Ganges and the Bramaputra are as holy or holier</sub>